# jquery closest() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab the closest link with the class `a.tariff-link` and send it to a method, but looks like `closest()` cannot find it because it's always passing an undefined element.

```
$(".ui-icon-triangle-1-e").click(function () {

    GetRuleData($(this).closest("a.tariff-link"));

});
```

An example of HTML would be like this:

```
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
<a id="41965" class="tariff-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">
</h3>
```

Comment: Read the documentation on `.closest()`. It gets the closest **parent**, not sibling child or cousin.

Comment: Closest beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead of `.closest()`. The latter checks the current element and its ancestors but your `a` is a *sibling* of the current element, not an ancestor.

If it's always the element right after the current element you could also use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Comment: `next()` is actually more appropriate in this case, although the difference is technically negligible. `siblings()` checks all siblings and not just elements following, it also doesn't stop when it finds the first element.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
GetRuleData($(this).next("a.tariff-link"));
```

Comment: hmm... I upvoted but then you added a horrible alternative... tempted to remove it.  Technically a better alternative would be to lose the selector for `next()` if it can be guaranteed that the <a> element will always immediately follow.